# How to get shipping info with Amazon's Product Advertising API

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I am working with Amazon's Product Advertising API and getting all product's information. I am getting everything but having problem with getting the shipping info. I have not seen any variable in the XML returned by the API. Once again, I am saying that I am getting all other information. I have even checked the URLs in `DetailPageURL` variable in a browser but there is no shipping info. It means the `searchindex` `kitchen` may not have any shipping info.

Now I want to ask If Amazon's API returns the shipping info? If so, in what variable is it returned in so that I can put a check in my code?

Comment: You are working with the Product Advertising API? By shipping info you mean you want to know how much the shipping costs?

Comment: @Jonathan Spooner yes dude you have understood right... I want to know the shipping costs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon's shipping charges vary by locale and most probably change frequently. The Product Advertising API does not have this info.

You can find more info about Amazon's shipping charges [here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_sn_sd?nodeId=468520) under the subheading **Shipping Rates and Times**

Answer (score 3):

Even though that data is not available through the Product Advertising API, you might have better luck using the [Marketplace Web Service](https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html/185-4772162-7621621) (you can use [this visualizer](http://www.roundsphere.com/visualize-mws-products/) to see what kind of data it returns)